# Using memcpy to initialize bit padded struct

Tags: c++, struct, standards, memcpy

Does anyone knows why initializing of bit padded struct is a "bad thing" and cannot be used?

For example:

```
struct parameter_set_t 
{
    std::uint8_t m_profile_idc;
    bool m_constraint_set0_flag: 1;
    bool m_constraint_set1_flag : 1;
    bool m_constraint_set2_flag : 1;
    bool m_constraint_set3_flag : 1;
    bool m_constraint_set4_flag : 1;
    bool m_constraint_set5_flag : 1;
    std::uint8_t m_reserved_zero_2bits : 2;
    std::uint8_t m_level_idc;
};

inline std::uint32_t bswap32(std::uint32_t v )  
{
    std::uint32_t ret_value = 0;
#if defined(__GNUC__) && (defined(__i386__) || defined(__x86_64__))
    ret_value = __builtin_bswap32(v);
#else
    ret_value = ((v & 0x000000FF) << 24) | ((v & 0x0000FF00) << 8) | ((v & 0x00FF0000) >> 8) | ((v & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
#endif
    return ret_value;
}

//! build from sdp 0xAABBCC string
profile_level_id( const std::string& sdp_value )
{
    //fetch profile_level_id value
    std::uint32_t int_value = std::stoul( sdp_value, nullptr, 16 );

    int_value = bswap32( int_value ) >> 8;

    std::memcpy( &m_parameters, &int_value, sizeof( parameter_set_t ) );
}
```

Comment: @SouravGhosh Oops, I misread as "should be tagged C"

Comment: Can you post the complete comment?

Comment: Nobody should call anything "a sh*t" without explaining why

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:standards]?

Comment: @imreal quote: "code is hack, violates c++ standart and with any unusual case will be working incorrectly and generates uninitialized data"

Comment: Out of curiosity, would using a copy constructor be more appropriate for your uses?

Comment: `profile_level_id` is illegal, functions must have a return value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that `std::memcpy` is used, but that it is used to copy between incompatible source and destination types.

The data is read from an unsigned integer of 32 bits, but it is written to a `parameter_set_t` structure, which has the size of 24 bits. Therefore, 8 bits of the `uint32_t` are dropped. This leaves us with two questions:

- Which 8 bits are dropped, the least significant or the most significant?
- How are the 24 bits of the integer that are kept distributed among the 24 bits of the `struct`?

The answer to both these questions is "it is platform-specific", which is a nice way of saying "completely non-portable". Hence the expletive in the comment about the quality of this code snippet.

Note that had the copying been done between two instances of `parameter_set_t`, the use of `std::memcpy` would be perfectly fine.

Comment: size of parameter_set_t = 3, parsed int is shifted by byte to the right. IOW: the high byte of parsed uin32_t intentionally drooped in memcpy call

Comment: @armigero You are right, I missed the `m_profile_idc` member when counting bits.

Comment: Wouldn't sizeof return 4 to pad out to the word boundary?

Comment: @armigero The byte at the highest numeric address of `int_value` may represent its most significant or its least significant part, depending on endianness. The use of `bswap32( int_value )` suggests that the code is written for hardware with a specific endianness in mind, meaning that it's not going to work on platforms with opposite endianness.